# How to understand escaping characters in document.queryselector?

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

Am looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#Escaping_special_characters

and I can't understand this section:

```js
// "#fooar" (\b is the backspace control character)
console.log('#foo\bar');
 // Does not match anything
document.querySelector('#foo\bar');

console.log('#foo\\bar'); // "#foo\bar"
console.log('#foo\\\\bar'); // "#foo\\bar"
document.querySelector('#foo\\\\bar');
```

```html
<div id="foo\bar"></div>
<div id="foo:bar"></div>
```

I'm a JavaScript beginner and don't understand why the 4 slashes, I found another similar question but I didn't understand the answers.

I tried to run `document.getElementById` on "foo\bar" and it works ok with 2 slashes which makes sense to me as you need an extra backslash to escape the first backslash but why an extra 3 when using querySelector?

I have looked at similar posts on here but the answers are not clear for me, I'm looking for a simple breakdown explanation of what's happening here and what the difference is between how getelementbyid works which I do understand (double backslash) and queryselector (which uses 4).

Comment: i don't understand the way the answer is explained in that post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the MDN Web Docs, about [litteral **Strings**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation):

> Besides regular, printable characters, special characters can be encoded using escape notation.
>
> - `\\` -> `\`

Now, about **`Document.querySelector`** [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#Escaping_special_characters):

> To match against an **ID** or **selectors** that **do not follow standard CSS syntax** (by using a colon or space inappropriately, for example), **you must escape the character with a backslash** ("\"). As the **backslash** is also an escape character in JavaScript, if you are entering a literal string, you must escape it ***twice*** (***once*** for the JavaScript string, and ***another time*** for querySelector()):

No such things is required for **`Document.getElementById`** (no explanation is given, maybe it's for legacy reason). Now, back to our question:

Consider the process as a two-pass formatting, let's view them **backwards**:

1. You need to send to **`querySelector`** a backslash. To fit the *requirement of* querySelector, You need to escape it once : `"#foo\\bar"`.
2. If you want to *represent* a backslash in a **Javascript String**, you need to escape it. Let's escape each backslash; we get `"#foo\\\\bar"`

Comment: Thanks hmm ok that feels a bit clearer but when using getelementbyid why does the same id get selected by using 2 slashes instead of 4?

Comment: Because `getElementById` may not have the same needs as `querySelector`.

Comment: can you just explain what you mean in 2 by javascript string? I'm not fully understanding why escaping once doesn't work for both the query selector and for the javascript string. Also in my original post I'm looking to understand why the getelementbyid doesn't need the same number of backslashes.

Comment: Javascript String = the way Javascript handles a litteral String. Special characters needs an "escape notation" (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation)). About `querySelector`, I'm gonna add some details in the answer.

Comment: Thanks I figured that 1 escape character e.g. "#foo\\bar" would be enough to cover escaping "\b" for both javascript and queryselector.


if "As the backslash is also an escape character in JavaScript, if you are entering a literal string, you must escape it twice (once for the JavaScript string, and another time for querySelector())"

Then doesn't that mean just 2 extra backslashes e.g. "#foo\\\bar" ?

Those 2 extra backslashes cover the javascript and queryselector requirement in the quote right?

Comment: Is a better way to understand it that a process is happening here where the javascript literal string is being parsed somehow and then passed to the queryselector?

Comment: 1. "Then doesn't that mean just 2 extra backslashes?" No you have to escape _each backslashes_: the backslash itself, and also the backslash used to escape it in the String representation. So, you end up getting 4 backslashes. 2. "Is a better way to understand it that a process is happening here [...] to the queryselector". Frankly, I tend to view it as an implementation choice of querySelector. They could have done it another way. View it as a requirement of this function. If you really want to know why it's designed this way, you should ask a new question (maybe not the right place).

Comment: @jobe: "Is a better way to understand it that a process is happening here where the javascript literal string is being parsed somehow and then passed to the queryselector?" Yes, there's two layers of parsing here: the JS string parsing (by the JS interpreter) and the selector parsing (by querySelector). As a rule of thumb, *every* literal backslash in a JS string should be represented by a double backslash. This means that a double backslash in a selector needs to be represented with a *quadruple* (4x) backslash.

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock for some reason the double parsing way of thinking about it helped me, I was thrown by the fact that getelementbyid doesn't have the same requirement but as Amessiehl explained it's just different implementations I guess.

Comment: @jobe: The difference is that getElementById takes an ID; querySelector takes a CSS selector, which have different grammars. There aren't any characters with special meanings in an ID that need escaping, but there are quite a few in a CSS selector.

Comment: @BoltClock Really? I thought you could use the same special characters for instance *$\ etc that you would need to escape?